# Как сделать динамический наклоненный квадрат?

Tags: html, css, html5

Можно ли сделать наклоненный на 45° динамический квадрат используя html + css? Нужно что бы он не был больше 1200px и не меньше 650px в уже наклоненном состоянии, и при этом менял свои пропорции в зависимости от размера экрана в этом промежутке. Я пробовал сделать несколькими способами вроде такого

```css
.square {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: -100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-width: 650px;
  transform-origin:bottom left;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: rotate(45deg)  ;
  background: #3A0085;
}
.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
  <div class="square"> </div>
```

Comment: так наклоненный или повернутый?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Хоть какой-то, лишь бы понять как это сделать)

Comment: А в чем собственно поблема? размер не тот? добавьте масштабирование

Comment: Я исправил ответ - теперь работает. @StrangerintheQ, проблема, насколько я понимаю, задать ограничения на размер и вписать эту штуку в document flow.

Comment: А ответ принять не планируется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно добавить к трансформам `scale(.7071)` что есть `1/sqrt(2)`

- Почему?

На столько сторона квадрата больше его диагонали.

```css
.square {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-width: 650px;
  transform-origin: center center;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: scale(.7071)rotate(45deg)  ;
  background: #3A0085;
}
.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"> </div>
```

Comment: Пустота сверху над углом. Можешь вписать в текст как у меня?

Comment: @Qwertiy пока нет, с компа сделаю, отвечал с телефона.

Comment: Ok, позови как сделаешь :)

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде так

Comment: Есть проблемы со скроллом https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLuxL.png. Но в целом да, работает.

Comment: Зачем ты ему абсолютное позиционирование и 100vw вместо 100% приделал?

Comment: @Qwertiy позиционирование-из вопроса..., я нажимал на кнопку переноса кода в вопрос

Answer (score 4):

Можно. Вот такой ромбик, который отлично вписывается в document flow:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 650px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 14.645% auto; /* (100 - 100/sqrt(2)) / 2 */
  width: 70.71%; /* 100/sqrt(2) */
  padding-top: 70.71%;
  background: silver;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
Можно ли сделать наклоненный на 45% динамический квадрат используя html + css?
<div></div>
Нужно что бы он не был больше 1200px и не меньше 650px в уже наклоненном состоянии
```

Comment: transform scale 1/sqrt(2)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, хороший вариант. Запостишь отдельным ответом?

Comment: я изначельно не хотел ибо это просто, предложил в комментарии, сейчас добавлю